# Install kernal drivers inside docker container

Tags: docker, containers, podman

My application using a kernal module for its process. Now we are moving to cloud and I have created our application as docker image(RHEL). Currently installed kernal module in host and shareing the location using -v option. But we need to install the kernal module inside the container and make our application to independent image.  Though containers are meant only user space applications and not kernal space need to install kernal module inside container. Any way to achieve this please let me know

Comment: PSA: It's "kernel". A [kernal is something else entirely](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Kernal).

Comment: Containers don't have a kernel they control, so I'm not sure you can do this, at least not without spinning up another kerne. You can use a VM, or, if really stuck, a VM inside a container.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really install kernel modules from inside a container.  This is generally prohibited since the kernel module would escape the container environment; even if you ran a privileged container, the requirement that the module has to be built for the exact version the host kernel is using would make it almost impossible to build a portable image.

If your application needs a specific kernel module to run, you either need to install it on the host or run the application in a virtual machine.  You mention "moving to cloud" and it's possible that running this application outside of a container on a dedicated general-purpose compute instance (*e.g.*, an AWS EC2 instance) is enough isolation for your needs.